# Query MongoDb collection by key in nested map (in Spring Boot Data)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm quite new to MongoDb, and trying to query by keys in a map on the documents. I've been trying to google things, but might not have the words needed to search for what I need yet.

These are my sample documents:

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60471bd482c0da3c0e70d26f"),
    obj: {
      "A": "1",
      "B": "2"
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("60471bd482c0da3c0e70d26e"),
    obj: {
      "C": "1",
      "D": "2"
    }
  }
]
```

And I want to query for the documents which has some key in `obj` equal to some value, for example `A`. I've been trying something like this: `{"obj.?": ?}`, which does not seem to work.

Any tips are appreciated, don't really know how to move on at this point.

Comment: As you've recognized, having any kind of data as field names creates query difficulties.  Because of this, it's generally considered a MongoDB _anti-pattern_.  A more workable data model might be something like `someArray: [{"label": "A", "value": "1"}, {"label": "B", "value": "2"}]`.

Comment: As mentioned by @rickhg12hs, It is anti-pattern. You should use attribute pattern to query the data efficiently. Please refer the link for more details of attribute pattern https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/building-with-patterns-the-attribute-pattern

Comment: I see, thank you! I'll be sure to use this method instead.